# Using ViewModel to get Live Data in Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mvvm

I need to observe livedata changes in a Modelview to update a fragment (Adding the list to a recyclerview).

The implementation is working correctly but facing problems when switching between fragments.

If the implementation is on `Fragment A` when the user switches to `Fragment B` and then back to `Fragment A` a second livedata observer gets initiated. (Data in recyclerview gets duplicated) and so on...

I did some research on the Fragment Lifecycle and the need to remove the observer when moving between fragments (Either on Fragment Detach/Destroy) or before creating a new observer in the OnActivityCreated. But any of these worked.

I am observing the livedata as: `mViewModel.getDetails().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), mObserver);`

And tried to remove the observer as: `mViewModel.getDetails().removeObservers(getViewLifecycleOwner())` or  `mViewModel.getDetails().removeObservers(this)` or  `mViewModel.getDetails().removeObserver(mObserver)` tried in `OnViewCreated` and `onDestroyView` and `onDestory` and `onDetach`

What is causing this and why removing the observer is not working?

FYI:

Here is the function i am using in the `MainActivity` to switch between fragments on navigation menu click

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //switching fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: pls, provide more details.
share your viewModel and both fragments.
I think it is not about the way you are loading the new fragment.

Comment: What could be the problem? Isn't it independent from the other fragment and the ViewModel since the functionality is correct before switching fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value to null after

```
mViewModel.getDetails().removeObservers(getViewLifecycleOwner()).
mViewModel.getDetails().setValue(null)
```

Comment: That would set the value to null in the modelView. Wrong Answer